# ASP.NET Core 6 Minimal API response JSON in camel case

Tags: json, asp.net-core-6.0, camelcasing

I want all JSON responses to use camel case, and tried below code, but it is not working and response is still in Pascal case. I also tried setting `[JsonPropertyName("myCamelCaseProperty")]` to override, but response still is in Pascal case.

Any suggestions how camel case can be made as default for all responses (all properties)?

```
builder.Services.Configure<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Json.JsonOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = false;
    options.SerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
});

builder.Build();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

Comment: you'd better to provide a minimal reproduciable sample, I also test in my .net 7 web api project both in swagger and in postman, it return response in camelCase by default.

Answer (score 0):

By Default .Net 6 gives response in Camel Case. Here is the screen shot of my model and response.

[image: Model]

Response:
[image: Response]

Comment: default for me is showing as Pascal case I am using postman to send request.

Answer (score 0):

In startup.cs :

```
builder.Services.Configure<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Json.JsonOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = false;
    options.SerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
});

builder.Build();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

Then install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson`

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="7.0.0" />
```

In you class reference above using `[JsonProperty("customName")]`

```
public class YourModel
{
    [JsonProperty("customName")]
    public string CustomName { get; set; }

    public string AnotherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but still JsonProperty is not used. What ever value i give in JsonProperty is not used and still it gives response in pascal case.